# How does zsh completion for tmux sessions work?

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, tmux

When I type `tmux a -t` and `Tab`, `zsh` shows a list of tmux sessions available for me. How does it work? If I have a user-defined command `xxx`, how can I make zsh completion work? Do I have to obey certain standards?

Comment: See the chapter [Writing your own completion functions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org).

Comment: Ultimately, there is a function `__tmux-sessions-separately` called which calls `tmux list-sessions` to see which sessions are active, and the output is used to populate the list of choices used by the completion function. You can look at `/usr/share/zsh/*/functions/_tmux`  (or wherever your `zsh` package stores the functions) to see how it all works.